# How to set spell checker in English?

Tags: support

I am french an my Windows system and web browser are set in french language. So when I am typing here (here = typing a question or an answer in BSE) nearly all the words are underlined and that does not help... How to set it in english ?

Comment: AFAIK the spell checker is part of your browser and not something that can be controlled by SE. I suggest searching around for docs relevant to your browser (in FF it's RMB on text field > languages), or even asking a question on [an SE site](http://superuser.com/) ;)

Comment: @gandalf3 Thanks ! RMB and languages works perfectly !

Comment: OK, off topic... but @gandalf3 gave me the answer. In my opinion "off topic" is very subjective here as I understood the meta was to help in practical aspects in BSE... but ok... the subject is solved for me. Maybe you should simply give an answer gandalf3 and the "debate" is closed.

Comment: Related: [How do we enhance the SE spell check dictionary?](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/755/2217)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As gandlaf said in the [comments](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1123/how-to-set-spell-checker-in-english#comment4654_1123), SE does not have any spell checker built in to the question or answer fields. All spell checking is handled by your browser. (Or if you are using a browser such as, say IE before version 10, you will get no spell checking.)

Here are the instruction to add spellchecking for other languages in [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-use-firefox-spell-checker#w_adding-dictionaries) and [Chrome](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/KfrcFpWZVcA) (yes the best instructions I could find for chrome was from their forum...)

Comment: Thanks David, it works... hope I will type a better English now !